# Double action on button click, how to do it good

Tags: android

i Create this for double action on click

```
private int pos = 0;

    private void changeImageVolumeOffOn() {
        buttonMuteVolume.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (pos == 0) {
                    pos++;
                    buttonMuteVolume.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.volume_off);
                } else {
                    pos--;
                    buttonMuteVolume.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.volume_on);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

But i think this is not good way for do this. I need emergency change the image only for showing it to my friends. How to do double action for click?

Comment: do you just want to change the image on every click?

Comment: Yes, my logic do this but i think the code is bad

Comment: is the your code not working???

Comment: @Rodriquez you can also do like get a image name  String imageName = (String)img.getTag();

Comment: working, but this code is something like "crazy" for me

Comment: @Rodriquez which code is working for u ?

Comment: check out my code in the answer

Comment: What do you mean by "Double Action"? Does it mean, single click-double click or onTouch-onClick-onLongPress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the if statement you could use a [ternary operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html)

```
boolean clicked = false;

private void changeImageVolumeOffOn() {
    buttonMuteVolume.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            clicked = !clicked;
            buttonMuteVolume.setBackgroundResource(clicked ? R.drawable.volume_off : R.drawable.volume_on);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean clicked = false;

private void changeImageVolumeOffOn() {
    buttonMuteVolume.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            clicked = !clicked;
            if (clicked) {
                buttonMuteVolume.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.volume_off);
            } else {
               buttonMuteVolume.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.volume_on);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: why do you want an int?

Comment: u cant implement true/false to int

Answer (score 0):

Use selector xml with two states drawable.
Selected - volume on
Not Selected - volume off

if any click happens 
boolean newState = button.isSelected()?false:true;
button.setSelected(newState);

This will solve your problem

Comment: can u say more? i create something like:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/volume_on" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/volume_off" />
</selector>

Comment: Set that selector as background to button.
buttonMuteVolume.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               boolean isSelected = v.isSelected();
v.setSelected(!isSelected;
            }
        });

Answer (score 0):

```
int isClicked=false

    buttonMuteVolume.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (isClicked) {
                buttonMuteVolume.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.volume_off);
                  isClicked=false;
            } else {
               buttonMuteVolume.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.volume_on);
                 isClicked=true;
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also try like this.

```
 private void changeImageVolumeOffOn() {
        buttonMuteVolume.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               String backgroundImageName = String.valueOf(v.getTag());
               if(backgroundImageName=="volume_off" ){
                   buttonMuteVolume.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.volume_on);
                }else {
                       buttonMuteVolume.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.volume_off);
              }
    }


            }
        });
    }
```